# How to add the exception handling row to the end of the exception handle using ASM

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I'm doing instrumentation for java code with ASM library.

I want to surround a method body with a try-catch block, which doesn't interrupt the origianl method execution. However, when I use `visitTryCatchBlock`, a dominant handler is registered at the beginning of the method's exception table.
Can I register the handler at the end of the method's exception table?

I couldn't really find examples of it online. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a [discussion on the ASM issue tracker](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/issues/317617) but was rejected as a feature. The exception table needs to be appended in the order it is written to the method attributes in the order it is visited.

> (...) it's one of those cases where the you know that you can do a better job than ASM that can not be easily fixed while remaining backward compatible, I'm against adding new flags for a corner cases given that there is a good chance of mis-using the API

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did need to visit the try-catch block in the order. I solved this by following your example: [Adding try/catch block in bytecode through ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491902/adding-try-catch-block-in-bytecode-through-asm) and moving `visitTryCatchBlock(start, end, handler, "java/lang/Exception");` from `visitCode` to `visitMaxs`. Since `visitMaxs` is after `visitTryCatchBlock`